# RestEase: ApiException doesn't fire

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-core

To implement an http interface, I'm using the RestEase plugin.

Following the official [documentation](https://github.com/canton7/RestEase#response-status-codes) i implemented a try catch with ApiException to manage the 400 and 500 status of http calls.

This is the Try Catch:

```
try
{
    var l = _provider.Api.GetHostListAsync();
    response.HttpResponseData = l.Result.Data;
    response.Status = "Success";
}
catch (ApiException ax)
{
    response.Status = "Error";
    _finalSuccess = false;
}
```

Here is the Interface:

```
[Header("User-Agent", "ComunicationLayer")]
public interface ISapi
{
    [Get("host")]
    Task<SapiGeneralResponse<List<Host>>> GetHostListAsync();
}
```

...and the Initialization:

```
Api = RestClient.For<ISapi>(url);
```

with the answers 200 everything is successful, the problem is when they return the 400 and the 500 that don't pass from ApiException.

To bypass the problem I tried to implement the attribute [AllowAnyStatusCode] in the interface call but in that case I get back an error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm using .NetCore 2.1.
Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

can try to change the interface into this:

```
Task<Response<List<Host>>> GetHostListAsync();
```

and change the code in try block into this:

```
using (var response = await _provider.Api.GetHostListAsync())
{
    if (response.ResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        // User wasn't found
    }
    else
    {
        var user = response.GetContent();
        // ...
    }
}
```

this can resolve your problem.

Comment: How does this answer the actual question if `ApiException` not being caught?!?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your exception isn't caught is because you use `l.Result.Data` without awaiting the task (plus it can create dead-locks depending on where you run it and which synchronization context is used).

```
try
{
    var l = _provider.Api.GetHostListAsync();
    response.HttpResponseData = l.Result.Data; // Don't do this
    response.Status = "Success";
}
catch (ApiException ax)
{
    response.Status = "Error";
    _finalSuccess = false;
}
```

When you call an async method (which returns a task, `async void` should be avoided except in UI application callbacks), you have to await it before you can access the result.

When you call `l.Result.Data` and there is an exception, it will throw an `AggregateException`, which inside it may contain your `ApiException` or some other exception type.

When you `await` the method, the actual exception will be thrown

Correct way to write that code is

```
try
{
    var l = await _provider.Api.GetHostListAsync();
    // l is now not a Task<T>, but T
    response.HttpResponseData = l.Data;
    response.Status = "Success";
}
catch (ApiException ax)
{
    response.Status = "Error";
    _finalSuccess = false;
}
```

Now when `GetHostListAsync()` throws `ApiException` it will be caught.

Alternative, when you are forced to run this code in a synch context, you can use

```
task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This also will throw `ApiException` instead of `AggregateException`.